# Ionic build error minCompileSdk with Android 10

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I started getting this error in ionic build...before now my project executed fine, trying again i get this error...please i need help... i have tried many options all to no avail

Error when i build

```
   * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
        > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
           > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
             dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
             is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
             Dependency: androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0.
             AAR metadata file: /private/var/root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fedb1dfce730f31190923d6e253eb6c6/transformed/browser-1.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

I am using android@10.

my build.gradle file looks like this

```
buildscript {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${cordovaConfig.AGP_VERSION}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    def hasRepositoriesGradle = file('repositories.gradle').exists()
    if (hasRepositoriesGradle) {
        apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    } else {
        apply from: "${project.rootDir}/repositories.gradle"
    }

    repositories repos
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed my problem by adding to android/app/build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
   // ... existing config
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0' }
    }
}
```